# Android studio Design is not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[Image Link for what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hECdF.png) I'm working on a project on Android Studio but the design part is just gone. I try to refresh, invalidate caches, and restart, debugging but none of them work. How can I bring it back and what it might be the reason it disappears?

Comment: What do you mean by "design part" and what do you mean by "gone"? Gone could mean something shows a blank screen,  or the option for it is grayed out, or the option for it is missing entirely, etc.

Comment: @Tenfour04 there's just a blank space, it's all black and middle of it 'toggle tools visibility and position' symbol which is supposed to be right top of the design.

Comment: To let people understand your issue, you should add a screenshot. Anyway, you can try to create a new project to see if it work

Comment: @VõQuangHòa I try to create new project but it didn't show the buttons I add, it just show the helloworld at the beginning. I add a screenshot to my question now

Answer (score -1):

Look that tab design in xml file not work well, you should update in build.gradle the support appcombat to androidx as below, if it doesn't work, please up your xml code for help

use

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'

instead of

```
com.android.support:appcompact-v7:25.3.1
```